# Explain a login process?

Tags: website-design, info-visualisation

I have developed a login process using 2 separate "blocks". You can call it public part and private (safe) part. My question is if this is a good way to explain the login process using a semi-carousel?

[Live "carousel"](https://login.go4webdev.org/login)

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by a 'semi-carousel'?

Comment: A standard carousel has all images loaded or lazy loaded at the beginning. My example is more of loading images when needed to innerHTML as you click on previous / next.  The semantic 'semi-carousel' may not be correct, but it is more technique behind.